# Keep reloading page until a set text appears (javascript - for greasekit)

Tags: javascript

I want to keep reloading page until `May 23rd, 2013` appears on a given page, BUT once it has appeared do nothing.

I am using Fluid.app with Greasekit so am looking to do this in Javascript. (There, I can make sure it only happens on my chosen page).

Answer (score 1):

call function `onload()` like this `<body onload="redirector()">` in javascript and check  the existence of string  May 23rd, 2013 on page.If not then use `location.reload()` function to reload the page.
"text1" is the id of  tag from which you wish to check the string.

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
function redirector()
{
    element=document.getElementById("text1");
    text=element.innerHTML;
    if(text=="your text")
    {
        location.reload();
     }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Cheers, could you please write that out for me in code? I will then accept your answer.

Comment: @Ted can you pls tell in which element is the string located?

Comment: sure, it's in a table in the body of the HTML document:

Comment: `<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">`

Comment: `<tr><td><p><b>Newsletter Issue Date: May 23rd, 2013</b><p>`

Comment: Hey, here is the HTML page: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5546881/for-stack-overflow-ted/for-swapn14.html

Comment: @Ted you have multiple tables and <b> tag in your html page.Better add id to <b> tag from where you wish to fetch the text and compare it with your string.

Comment: I cannot amend the HTML on the page, sadly, So I cannot add  id :(

Comment: Ah, this might help: the XPath where the string is located is `/HTML[1]/BODY[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[3]/TD[1]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR[1]/TD[1]/P[1]/B[1]`

Comment: (also I removed the <script> tags, as when using Greasekit, it already knows it's Javascript)